# dx.bat failure when compiling using android studio

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-studio

Compiling has been fine but now when I try and run my application i get this error come up:

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':AppName:dexDebug'.
>   Running C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat failed. See output

I am using the latest android studio v0.1.9. Is there a fix for this or do I have to copy my code to eclipse and continue using that until this problem has been fixed?

Comment: have you done anything about the instruction in message that says **"See output"**?

Comment: The problem with that is that Google have not implemented looking at that "Output" yet. I know you can look at some degree by using CMD but I haven't found documentation of it that works with my error.